# Dynamically changing a WPF ListView between one that contains a GridView with column headers and another view that doesn't

Tags: wpf, listview, view, dynamic

I'm not quite sure how to go about this so any advice would be much appreciated.

I have a ListView whose default implementation is using  with column headers. At runtime in the program I would like to be able to click on a button at runtime to change the view so that the list view loses the GridViewColumn headers and implements a new style using one of my own data template.

Then I would also like the ability to click the button and change the ListView back to a grid view with column headers.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction of how to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since ListView.View is dependency property, you can bind it to something on your VM via converter.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a sample that demonstrate how to create a ListView control that displays data in multiple view modes, which include the GridView and other custom view modes.

Search for **ListView with Multiple Views Sample** in the **WPF Documentation Sample** page.
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples

Here is a direct link to download the sample:
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7766